# Selecting text from Edit Text and converting selected text into an image

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating an edittext in android and i am able to select particular text in it, I want to convert the selected text into a bitmap or png image..
Is it possible

Comment: Text into image? Interesting!!

Comment: this sounds great, its notable question

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom class that extends `ImageView`... then, you override the `onDraw` method and use the canvas object to draw the text... something like this:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, null);
}
```

You can also use a `Paint` object in order to format and change the text color. Here you have an example:

```
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
textPaint.setTextSize(32);
StaticLayout layoutText = new StaticLayout(textToDraw, textPaint,
    coordX, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 1, true);
```

Once you have create the `ImageView` you could use the [`getDrawingCache` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29) in order to get a Bitmap.

The advantage of using a `ImageView` subclass is that you could easly show the image into your application before you do whatever you want to do with the Bitmap.